# SQL Union Query - Referencing to alias of derived table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a complicated aggregate-functions query that produces a result-set, and which has to be amended with a single row that contains the totals and averages of that result-set.

My idea is to assign an alias to the result-set, and then use that alias in a second query, after a UNION ALL statement.

But, I can't successfully use the alias, in the subsequent SELECT statement, after the UNION ALL statement.

For the sake of simplicity, I won't post the original query here, just a simplified list of the variants I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM fees AS Test1 WHERE Percentage = 15
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM fees AS Test2 WHERE Percentage > 15)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM fees AS Test3 WHERE Percentage < 10) AS Test4)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test3
```

The result is:

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1146 - Table 'xxxxxx.Test3' doesn't exist
```

The result is the same if the last query references to the table Test1, Test2, or Test4.

So, how should I assign an alias to a result-set/derived table in earlier queries and use that same alias in latter queries, all within a UNION query?

Amendment:

My primary query is:

```
SELECT

COALESCE(referrers.name,order_items.ReferrerID),

SUM(order_items.quantity) as QtySold,

ROUND(SUM((order_items.quantity*order_items.price+order_items.shippingcosts)/((100+order_items.vat)/100)), 2) as TotalRevenueNetto,

ROUND(100*SUM(order_items.quantity*order_items.purchasepricenet)/SUM((order_items.quantity*order_items.price+order_items.shippingcosts)/((100+order_items.vat)/100)), 1) as PurchasePrice,

ROUND(100*SUM(order_items.quantity*COALESCE(order_items.calculatedfee,0)+order_items.quantity*COALESCE(order_items.calculatedcost,0))/SUM((order_items.quantity*order_items.price+order_items.shippingcosts)/((100+order_items.vat)/100)), 1) as Costs,

ROUND(100*SUM(order_items.calculatedprofit) / SUM( (order_items.quantity*order_items.price + order_items.shippingcosts)/((100+order_items.vat)/100) ) , 1) as Profit,

COALESCE(round(100*Returns.TotalReturns_Qty/SUM(order_items.quantity),2),0) as TotalReturns

FROM order_items LEFT JOIN (SELECT order_items.ReferrerID as ReferrerID, sum(order_items.quantity) as TotalReturns_Qty FROM order_items WHERE OrderType='returns' and OrderTimeStamp>='2017-12-1 00:00:00' GROUP BY order_items.ReferrerID) as Returns ON Returns.ReferrerID = order_items.ReferrerID LEFT JOIN `referrers` on `referrers`.`referrerId` = `order_items`.`ReferrerID`

WHERE ( ( order_items.BundleItemID in ('-1', '0') and order_items.OrderType in ('order', '') ) or ( order_items.BundleItemID is NULL and order_items.OrderType = 'returns' ) ) and order_items.OrderTimestamp >= '2017-12-1 00:00:00'

GROUP BY order_items.ReferrerID
ORDER BY referrers.name ASC
```

I want to make a grand-total of all the rows resulting from query above with:

```
SELECT 'All marketplaces', SUM(QtySold), SUM(TotalRevenueNetto), AVG(PurchasePrice), AVG(Costs), AVG(Profit), AVG(TotalReturns) FROM PrimaryQuery
```

I want to do this with a single query.

Comment: mysql != sql server, please don't tag products not involved. You can do what you want using `CTE`.

Comment: I'll be more precise with the query. What I need is a functioning equivalent to: SELECT * FROM fees AS Test UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Test, i.e. a way to reference to an earlier result-set within a UNION query. Joe Taras explained why this is happening, but a concrete example in code would be great.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, does MySQL support cte's?

Comment: @jarlh, according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-syntax) it does.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, thanks for the info!

Comment: @HoneyBadger: If I'm not mistaken MySQL 8 is only available as a preview version so far. I think MySQL 5.7 is the current official version and doesn't support CTEs.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Ah...looks like you're right, missed that little word 'Draft'... That's unfortunate, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Nightcrawler: Please tell us what you want to achieve exactly. `UNION ALL` queries are not that common. You'd use them sometimes on similar tables (`select item, amount from sales union all select item, -amount from purchases`) and sometimes even on the same table (`select sender as person from chat union all select recipient as person from chat`). As you see, the latter is used in order to get multiple rows from a single record. Maybe what you are looking for is rather a slightly more complicated `WHERE` clause instead.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: So, with MySQL 5.x one must repeat/copy the code (like in scaisEdge's answer) and there's no other way around?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: I have a complex GROUP BY primary query that provides totals of product-sales (total revenue from particular product, total profit expressed in percents, etc.), grouped by productID, with similarly-complex WHERE condition. I want to amend that resulting result-set, with one bottomline - grand totals for all productID's combined. The secondary query uses SUM() and AVERAGE(), but without GROUP BY - to result with a single row, but I don't want to repeat the same code two times and seek a way how to reference to the result-set of the primary query.

Comment: That is usually done with `ROLLUP` in SQL (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) or simply with a programming language in your app instead. You may also want to show us the real query, so we can help you on that.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: I've included the real queries in the edited post. Thanks!

Comment: @Nightcrawler, please see my edited answer, I've added an alternative method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are attempting to solve, but I guess something like the following:

Hypothetical 'main' query:

```
SELECT    T1.ID
,         Sum(total_grade)/COUNT(subjects) as AverageGrade
FROM      A_Table T1
JOIN      AnotherTable T2
      ON  T2.id = T1.id
GROUP BY  T1.ID
```

You want sub resultsets, without having to keep querying the same data.

**Edit**: I mistakenly thought the linked documentation and method mentioned below was for the current version of mySQL. It is however a draft for a future version, and CTE's are **not** currently supported.

In the absence of CTE support, I would probably just insert the resultset into a temporary table. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE(ID INT, AverageGrade DECIMAL(15, 3))

INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE
        SELECT    T1.ID
        ,         Sum(total_grade)/COUNT(subjects) as AverageGrade
        FROM      A_Table T1
        JOIN      AnotherTable T2
              ON  T2.id = T1.id
        GROUP BY  T1.ID

SELECT ID, AverageGrade FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE AverageGrade > 5
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS TotalCount, SUM(AverageGrade) AS Total_AVGGrade FROM TEMP_TABLE

DROP TABLE TEMP_TABLE
```

(Disclaimer: I'm not too familiar with mySQL, there may be some syntax errors here. The general idea should be clear, though.)

That is, of course, if i *had* to do it like this, there are probably better ways to achieve the same. See Thorsten Kettner's comments on the matter.

---

**(Previous answer assuming CTE is a posibility:)**

A [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-syntax) approach looks like:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT    T1.ID
    ,         Sum(total_grade)/COUNT(subjects) as AverageGrade
    FROM      A_Table T1
    JOIN      AnotherTable T2
          ON  T2.id = T1.id
    GROUP BY  T1.ID
)

SELECT ID, AverageGrade FROM CTE WHERE AverageGrade > 5
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS TotalCount, SUM(AverageGrade) AS Total_AVGGrade FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thanks Joe Tarras for explaining why it isn't possible to make such a query right away, and thanks Thorsten Kettner for taking the time to look at the original query and suggesting the ROLLUP solution. However I couldn't use the ROLLUP solution because some of the fields are expressed in percentages (of varying wholes, i.e. of variable impact to the bottomline), so neither SUM nor AVG would suffice, and a whole new query is necessary to calculate the bottomline (the secondary query). Therefore, in absence of CTE, the only solution seems to be to create a temp table and delete it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is well-written. You may be able to get a total line by using a surrounding query with a dummy `GROUP BY` clause and `WITH ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(Referrer, 'All marketplaces'),
  SUM(QtySold) AS QtySold,
  SUM(TotalRevenueNetto) AS TotalRevenueNetto,
  AVG(PurchasePrice) AS PurchasePrice,
  AVG(Costs) AS Costs,
  AVG(Profit) AS Profit,
  AVG(TotalReturns) AS TotalReturns
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    COALESCE(referrers.name,order_items.ReferrerID) AS Referrer,
    SUM(order_items.quantity) AS QtySold,
  ...
) PrimaryQuery
GROUP BY Referrer ASC WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the error because every query involved in `UNION` doens't know the alias of other.

DB Engine execute, in your case, 4 queries and then paste them with UNION operation.

Your real table is `fees`. Test3 is an alias used in the third query.

If you want to process the results of `UNION` operation, you must encapsulate your queries in a MAIN query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something like below. Please try

```
SELECT * FROM fees AS Test2 WHERE Percentage >= 15
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM fees AS Test3 WHERE Percentage < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a table alias  based on a subquery (is not in the scope of the outer united  select)  you must repeat the code eg:

```
SELECT * FROM fees AS Test1 WHERE Percentage = 15
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM fees AS Test2 WHERE Percentage > 15
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM fees AS Test3 WHERE Percentage < 10
    ) AS Test4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM fees AS Test3 WHERE Percentage < 10
```